# passing in nullable Expression<Func<T, TResult>>? as method parameter?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

So i have a method

```
public IPagedList<MyObject> GetAll<T>(Expression<Func<MyObject, T>>? orderBy, 
    int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10)
{
    return dataContext.MyObjects
      .OrderBy(orderBy.HasValue ? orderBy.Value : <WHAT GOES HERE?>)
      .ToPagedList<MyObject>(pageNumber, pageSize);
}
```

My goal is to have the `orderBy` parameter optional, if `orderBy` is `null` then default the order to the property `MyObject.Id`.

I've tried `.OrderBy(orderBy.Hasvalue ? orderBy.Value : x => x.Id)` but getting this error:

`Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Func<MyObject, T>' and 'lambda expression'`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: does this compile with question mark? `Expression<Func<MyObject, T>>?`

Comment: `Expression<>` is a reference type. It cannot be made `Nullable<>`, `Nullable<>` only applies to value types.

Comment: @KirkWoll I know, that's why I'm asking.it should give that error before conversion

Comment: AH! I see where I went wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code

- [`Expression<TDelegate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a class, so it's nullable already; you can simply test if `orderBy == null`. [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a generic constraint that `T` must be a `struct`, so `Expression<Func<MyObject, T>>?` won't compile.
- Next you'll have the problem that because the type `T` isn't bound inside the method, but `x.Id` is. In other words, you won't be able to create use the conditional operator to choose between a value of `Expression<Func<MyObject, T>>` and `Expression<Func<MyObject, int>>` (assuming that `Id` is an `int`) while still maintaining type information to pass to the `OrderBy` method.

The solution is to use something along these lines:

```
public IPagedList<MyObject> GetAll<T>(Expression<Func<MyObject, T>> orderBy, 
    int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10)
{
    IQueryable<MyObject> objects = dataContext.MyObjects;
    objects = (orderBy != null) ? objects.OrderBy(orderBy) 
                                : objects.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
    return objects.ToPagedList<MyObject>(pageNumber, pageSize);
}
```

The conditional operator works in this code because regardless of what you pass to `OrderBy` the return type will be the same, `IQueryable<MyObject>`.

Note also that you can't simply pass in a null value for `orderBy`, because `T` can't be inferred. You'd have to call it like this:

```
var results = MyClass.GetAll<int>(null);
```

Ultimately, you'd probably be better off creating two overloads, one that accepts an `orderBy` expression, and one that doesn't.

Comment: or you can make the expression parameter optional as well: `GetAll<T>(Expression<Func<MyObject, T>>? orderBy = null`

Comment: @Selman22 I think you meant to remove the `?` from your comment.  You'd still have to call it like `MyClass.GetAll<int>()`, even though `int` (or whatever type parameter you pass) is not used in any way. I'd still recommend an overload that you can call with no `orderBy` and no type parameter.